# Add last row to DataGridView that fills with sum of the whole column C#

Tags: c#

I need to fill a row that sums the total of the column and always is at the bottom of the DataGridView. I use SQL to fill the DataGridView. It could be a TextBox too, just need it to be at the bottom of the DataGridView.

Comment: Yes, but im using DGVPrinter to print the datagridview, and i need the textbox to appear in the dgvprinter generated file

Comment: Couldn’t you just put a `TextBox` strategically placed below the grid to hold the total of the column(s)? As opposed to being IN the grid? I am just saying that if the grid is data bound, then you would have to add this row to the grid’s data source as you will not be able to add rows to the grid directly. This also would mean that you will have to “move” the totals row every time new rows are added.

Comment: If you are using an SQL to populate it, thnen you can use an old indian trick and in your SQL add last row as the aggregate.